# Delay in loading asp.net web page after application pool recycle in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, compilation

I have a web application with master page(.master) and many content pages(.aspx). All the .aspx(content pages) pages are placed in different folders.

When i access the web application **for the first time**, for loading the default page(Home page) its taking time, this is expected as the server tries to compile and load the pages for the first time(correct me if i am wrong).

Once the default home page is loaded then when i tried to navigate to other aspx pages, it is still taking time to load. Why do this happen, the pages are already compiled when home page is loaded.

Do the server compile only the files in root folder while processing the first request?

When a user requests for a particular page which is placed in a folder, are all other pages with in the folder are compiled as well?

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: can i get any kind of help here?

Comment: These may apply and be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387123/how-to-warm-up-an-asp-net-mvc-application-on-iis-7-5 and http://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle

Comment: And this may be more applicable (not MVC-oriented) to your application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917205/iis-7-5-web-application-first-request-after-app-pool-recycle-very-slow?rq=1

Comment: It doesn't compile and load all pages when you first access the web application: it only compiles the page you access.  Other pages will be compiled on demand when they are first accessed.

Comment: @Joe In my solution structure there are multiple folders, folder 1 has a login page, folder 2 has around 30 pages. When i access a page in folder 1 it loaded quickly, but when i access a page from folder 2 its taking around 10 seconds to load. Any idea why this happens ??